# How do i sort data in a csv file to a standardized output, While reading headers to sort data

Tags: c#, csv, file, sorting, credit-card

**INPUT**
[image: INPUT]

**OUTPUT**
[image: OUTPUT]

I need to know how can i read different people's details and arrange, as Rahul and Ritu are in the same column so I will need to allot the following transactions after ritu's name to ritu how can I do this? Simmilar for International and Domestic transactions.

Comment: https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, first of all you need to create two models:

```
class Person
{
  public string Name {get; set;}
  public List<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }
}

enum TransactionType
{
  Domestic,
  International
}

class Transaction
{
  public Person Owner { get; set; }
  public DateTimeOffset Date { get; set; }
  public string TransactionDescription { get; set; }
  public TransactionType TransactionType { get; set; }

  //and so on
}
```

But the problem is that input file is not standard csv nor json file. So you will have to parse it by yourself to such domain as I proposed.

Next you can have a list of such transactions and order it by date using Linq:

```
//using System.Linq;

List<Transaction> transactions = GetTransactionsSomehow();
transactions.OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```

And that's really it.